# Blackjack simulator with classes

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and trying to make a Blackjack simulator. The Player is a class that stores cards dealt from the deck; class Card contains a suit value and a face value. I keep getting error message "Control may reach end of non-void function" for Card Player::getCard( int index ) const, what did I do wrong? Also can someone check if there is any logic flaws in my code since I can't run it and check because of the error message?

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include "Card.h"
using namespace std;

Player::Player( )
{
    // The Player has no Cards in his hand
    myNumberOfCards = 0;
}

std::ostream& operator <<( std::ostream& outs, const Player & p )
{
    // print out all the actual cards in the array myCards
    for (int i = 0; i < p.cardCount(); i++)
    {
        outs << p.myCards[i] << endl;
    }
    return( outs );
}

void Player::acceptCard(Card c)
{
    // as long as there is space in the array myCards, place Card c into myCards
    //        if there is not enough space for another card, throw an exception
    try
    {
        for (; myNumberOfCards < MAXCARDS; myNumberOfCards++)
            myCards[ myNumberOfCards ] = c;
        if (myNumberOfCards > MAXCARDS)
            throw myNumberOfCards;
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        std::logic_error( "more than maximum of cards possible" ); // Since the player must be busted if he has more than 11 cards, how should I set the outcome to playerbusted if I have a bool in the game class?
    }
}

Card Player::getCard( int index ) const
{
    // return the requested card
    // if the index is bad, throw an exception
    try
    {
        while ( index > 0 && index < myNumberOfCards )
            return ( myCards[ index ] );
        if (index < 0 || index > myNumberOfCards)
            throw index;
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        std::logic_error( "bad index" ); // why there's an error?
    }
}

int Player:: cardCount() const
{
    //  return the number of cards stored in my array
    return myNumberOfCards;
}

int  Player::handcount( ) const
{
    // total up the points in this player's hand
    // Ace's might be worth 1 or 11
    Player p;
    int total = 0;
    bool hasAce = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < myNumberOfCards; i++)
    {
        total += myCards[i].count();
        if (myCards[i].getFace() == ACE)
            hasAce = true;
    }
    if (total < 11 && hasAce == true)
        total += 10;
    return( total );
}


bool Player::hasBlackJack( ) const
{
    bool result = false;
    if (myNumberOfCards == 2 && handcount() == 21)
    {
        result = true;
    }
    return( result );
}
```

Comment: _"... since I can't run it and check because of the error message?"_ What about fixing that error first?

Comment: The loop in `getCard` is equivalent to a conditional; it will execute once or not at all. A simpler variant is `if (index < 0 || index >= myNumberOfCards) throw std::logic_error("bad index"); else return myCards[index];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// vvvv must return a Card
   Card Player::getCard( int index ) const
{
    try
    {
        // ...
            throw index;
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        std::logic_error( "bad index" ); // this doesn't throw, so will continue past
    }
    // ends up here, doesn't return
}
```

You don't throw a `std::logic_error`, just construct one in place and then do nothing with it.

In the event of an error that hits `throw index`, you end up hitting the bottom of the function without returning anything, which is [*Undefined Behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (very bad, anything can happen).

Probably you meant to `throw std::logic_error("bad index");`? This would cause you to exit the function with an exception, rather than normal returning, so wouldn't cause the problem.

It would just be simpler to get rid of the `try`/`catch` in `getCard`, and replace

```
throw index;
```

with

```
throw std::logic_error("bad index");
```

since the end result to the caller is the same. And ditch the `while`, since it isn't really a loop, just a check. Here's the simplified version:

```
Card Player::getCard( int index ) const
{
    // return the requested card
    // if the index is bad, throw an exception
    if ( index > 0 && index < myNumberOfCards )
        return ( myCards[ index ] );
    else
        throw std::logic_error("bad index");
}
```

You make the same error in `acceptCard`, but since it returns `void`, you don't see the error message: "falling off the bottom" of a `void` function is allowed, it acts like the last line is just `return;`.

---

Also, please reconsider your use of bad practices [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191) and [`endl`](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/why-you-shouldnt-use-stdendl.html).

Comment: My teacher didn't really talk about this in class... why is "using namespace std;" and "endl" worse than "std::cin/cout" and "\n"?

Comment: @553535782 Note that both of those are links to descriptions that would be too big to fit into the comments. The first an SO question with good answers, the second a blog post I wrote up because I didn't find a good explanation (so bear in mind, no one has been able to vote it up or down, since it isn't on SO).